# jQuery and Native JavaScript Array - error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var tmpANArray = [];
for (var i in associatedPpl) {
    tmpANArray.push(associatedPpl[i]);
}
alert('about to call toJSON on AssociatedPpl');
alert(tmpANArray);
// the next line fails because $.toJSON is getting fed a function
var jsonEncodedAssociatedPpl = $.toJSON(tmpANArray);
```

What part of JavaScript/jQuery am I missing?

**UPDATE**
The JS JSON lib was jquery.json-1.3.min.js

Comment: What are you using for the $.toJSON - that isn't a part of jquery. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: He's using http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/ probably.

Comment: What does `associatedPpl` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your for cycle wrong, it is actually a foreach so your i variable should not be used to index the array, because its the value itself, change it to:

```
var tmpANArray = [];
for (var i in associatedPpl) {
    tmpANArray.push(i);
}
```

Or why not use the associatedPpl array directly?

Comment: weird that I missed that. Wondering what about associatedPpl[i] returns a function though.

Answer (score 0):

there's no toJSON natively in Jquery.  Do you mean to use getJSON()?  Are you involving a function that you haven't provided information about?

getJSON documentation:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: He didnt mention it, but I think he's using http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/